# Add pictures to contacts (fast for many)

Tags: contacts, images

S4 I9505, Resurrection remix 5.6.5 Marshmallow 6.01

As the title is saying I want to add some pictures to contacts. I have nearly 550 contacts and for 400 I have local pictures, which I want to add.

(pictures are named as contacts)

I know the 2 ways (select contact and add photo/ select pictures, and set as contact photo), but for 400 pictures is taking too long..

Is there a faster way to do this? I was thinking for a drag and drop procedure...(on left column contacts, on right column pictures... ) if exists..

or through adb... or any other method which is faster than this

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think there is such a batch procedure for adding contact pictures. If you are storing your contacts in your Google account, you may use [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) to add the pictures, which may be faster than doing it on your phone.

Comment: That's the point, cause I am storing my contacts locally...